# SQL - calculating percentage columns grouped by month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I have a table which has a date time column for timestamp and a bit column for pass/fail e.g.

```
Timestamp                     Pass
2018-01-19 07:01:42.000         1
2018-01-19 07:05:42.000         0
```

I can group by year / month to show the total passes per month:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp) AS Month,
        COUNT(Timestamp) as Total
    FROM table
    WHERE Pass  = 1
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp)
```

What I need is to also display the total results per month (pass and fail), and if possible display the percentage passed e.g.

```
Year    Month    Passes   Total   Percentage Pass
2018      1       2729     3275       83.32
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp) AS Month,
        SUM(CAST(Pass AS INT)) AS Passes,
        COUNT(*) as Total,
        CAST(1.00*SUM(CAST(Pass AS INT)) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5,2) AS PercentagePass -- 1.00 is used to avoid integer maths
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp)
```

Comment: Multiplying by `1.00` does not convert to `FLOAT`, it converts to `DECIMAL(14, 2)` (because `SUM(Pass)` is `INT`, or it would be, if `Pass` was converted to the `INT` it needs to be). That's not a bad thing, but it makes the comment slightly misleading. If you really wanted to have a `FLOAT`, you would multiply by `1e`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp) AS Month,
        SUM (CAST (Pass AS TINYINT)) AS Passes,
        COUNT(*) as Total,
        CAST (SUM (Pass) AS Money) / COUNT(*) AS Percentage
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,Timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH,Timestamp)
```

Comment: `Pass` is a `BIT` and can't be summed without converting it first. What's the deal with `MONEY`? That just looks needlessly confusing as opposed to an explicit numeric type (and can confuse client tools into displaying it wrong). Just for display I'd use `FORMAT(1. * SUM(CONVERT(INT, Pass)) / COUNT(*), '0.00%')`, but if the percentage had to be retained as a number I'd throw in a `DECIMAL` conversion.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, I edited the answer. The MONEY datatype comes is handy, since it's the fastest way to get a float result. But your way is more pure, I must admit. A matter of taste, I suppose.

Comment: I'm aware of the perf benefits of `MONEY` (it's not just shorter typing, it actually calculates faster than a `DECIMAL`), but since in this case the division is happening at the end of the aggregates, it's not going to buy you much over the confusion it's introducing. Even if you used it in an inner calculation, you probably want to convert it at the end regardless.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've never seen anyone being confused as to what the point of MONEY in these types of situations is. But let's agree to disagree.